# List of distinct values after group by on other columns

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to get a list of distinct values (instead of their counts by `func.count(distinct(column))`) after I grouping on other columns. How can I do this in MySQL/SQLAlchemy efficiently?

For example, the following is trivial but I'd like to get the list of distinct `col1` values.

```
SELECT col2, col3, count(distinct col1)
FROM table
GROUP BY col2, col3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT col2, col3, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT col1)
FROM table
GROUP BY col2, col3
```

Each row will be a comma-separated string.

It will be efficient if there's an index on `(col2, col3)`.

Comment: But you wouldn't know which result belonged to which col2,col3 combination, rendering the exercise rather futile :-(

Comment: Yes, in this query you wouldn't but you can just add col2, col3 to selected columns.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` is cool. Is there a way I can get a set/list instead? Or would I need to write my custom group_concat function

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a set or list datatype.

Comment: @Strawberry He doesn't know that in the original `COUNT` query, either.

Comment: Although trivial, this looks like the correct answer to me.